# How do I change date picker format for admin date field

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, admin, adminform, date

How can I change the date format to display as **dd/mm/yyyy** for admin date field?

Currently it is displaying as **mm/dd/yyyy** format. Can you please help me out?

[image]

Comment: this is a bug in magento 2 which is already reported, for its progress you can check it here : https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6858

Answer (score 0):

**=> Try to use this date format in your xml file :**

```
<column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created At</item>
            <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">dd-MM-YYYY HH:mm:ss</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</column>
```

Comment: This will change only on GRID not on the add/edit form.